# Adding values up in sqlite db and displaying the sum in EditText

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database helper class:

```
public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);

    return res;
}
```

Which works fine when I want to display all the data from a button in an activity, i.e:

```
public void onbtnViewAllRecordsClick(View v) {
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();

    if(res.getCount() == 0) {
        // Show message
        showMessage("Error", "No data found");
        return;
    }

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        buffer.append("ID " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
        buffer.append("Amount " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
        buffer.append("Cost " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
        buffer.append("Date " + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
    }

    // Show all data
    showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());
}
```

I'm now trying to figure out how to get certain detail from the database when the app is loaded and display it on the default activity.  I have an EditText on the default activity, and want to add up all the 'Amount' values in the database, and display it within the EditText.

Can someone point me in the write direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the values you want to add are integers here is what you can do.

1. get the values from the data base on the default activities `onCreate` method
2. Now when you have the data retrieve the specific value you want to add and show them summing them up in the edit text like in the following example

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_default);
       ...
       ...
       displayValues();
       ...
       ...
   }

   private void displayValues(){
       Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();

       if(res.getCount() == 0) {
       // Show message
       showMessage("Error", "No data found");
       return;
       }

       StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
       int total = 0;
       // assuming here that you only have to add the Amount values    
       while (res.moveToNext()) {
       //hear you can initilize variables or arrays with the other values from your db which you want to use further.
       total +=res.getInt(1);//addind up all the values of Amount column
       }

       yourEditText.setText(""+total);
   }
   ```